# How to Display the Poster on the video when Video Gets Pause by User

Tags: javascript, video, hover

I did some javascript for the video, like when you hover on video then 
that video will play and when you hover out from video, the video will pause....
But I want to do more, I want to display the poster on the video when the video gets Pause, the poster I have included to my video attribute..
And I want to use the same javascript for all the different videos with different posters.
Here is the code which I am using currently.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>video hover</title>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <video controls loop data-play="Hover" preload="auto" poster="MyPoster.jpg" height="300" width="500" muted="muted">
    <source src="Myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>


 <script type="text/javascript">

    var vid=document.getElementsByTagName("video");
    [].forEach.call(vid,function(item){
        item.addEventListener('mouseover',hovervideo,false);
        item.addEventListener('mouseout',hidevideo,false);


    });

    function hovervideo(e)
    {

       this.play();
    }

    function hidevideo(e)
    {
        this.pause();

    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is JSFiddle :- https://jsfiddle.net/vpoL6a5w/1/

Comment: Its not possible using just the video element, check above question

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the link provided by Anurag Srivastava. Showing an overlay is your best option here.

You can do that by wrapping your video in a div element and adding an image as cover with the same src as the video poster.

In the hover function you can select a sibling and add/remove a hidden class.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>video hover</title>
  <style>
.video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.cover-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.cover-img.hidden {
  display: none;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="video-wrapper" height="300" width="500">
    <video controls loop data-play="Hover" preload="auto" poster="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" height="300" width="500" muted="muted">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"/ type="video/mp4">
    </video> 
    <img class="cover-img hidden" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" />
   </div>


 <script type="text/javascript">

    var vid=document.getElementsByTagName("video");
    [].forEach.call(vid,function(item){
        item.addEventListener('mouseover',hovervideo,false);
        item.addEventListener('mouseout',hidevideo,false);


    });

    function hovervideo(e)
    {   
    var coverImg = e.target.parentNode.children[1];
    coverImg.classList.add('hidden')
   this.play();
    }

    function hidevideo(e)
    {
  var coverImg = e.target.parentNode.children[1];
  coverImg.classList.remove('hidden')
        this.pause();

    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```